# Evolution Alarm Notify displays inaccurate calendar details

Tags: notification, evolution, calendar

Ubuntu 20.10: Evolution Alarm Notify seems to be displaying calendar events which were copied from my Google calendar, possibly when upgrading to 20.04, and have not been updated since. I don't want the calendar notifications at all, and I don't want to be told about repeating events which were deleted long ago.  Cannot see where or how to correct the diary entries or to stop displaying them.

Update: I don't have Evolution installed.  At least, when I scroll through the installed programs, Evolution is not listed.  So I cannot use Evolution to view or edit any settings, unless someone can tell me how to do it from the command line.

Comment: You have to try the following: open Evolution and locate view/edit calendar with its events here.

Comment: I don't seem to have Evolution installed, so no way to open it ...

Comment: Some parts of evolution seem to get installed with the various desktops. My 18.04 Ubuntu system has `evolution-data-server` installed. My 20.04 MATE system has `evolution-data-server-common` installed. Neither has `evolution` installed.

Comment: Organic Marble - thank you: that confirms my understanding of the current setup.  And, implicitly confirms one aspect of the problem: if I don't have Evolution installed. I can't use it to view or edit the settings.

Which raises another question: should I attempt to install Evolution, so that I can try to fix the problem that way, or is that likely to make the situation more complicated?

Answer (score -1):

Open Calendar from the list of apps. You can delete items there.